# is there a api to fetch aws cloud account owner information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to find a api to know the cloud account owner email address in case of aws cloud account . can some one help ? i see a api for the case where account belongs to aws organisation , my requirement is ,I need the api for stand alone aws accounts , any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to use programmatic methods to access email address of *Root user* of a standalone AWS account. You must log in to the console using Root credentials to view or update the email address.